# Change of content of UITextField and recocnize new line

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I have a `UIButton` and a `UITextView`, now when I write something on textview and submit the button the textview content is showing over a UIView , but If I write in the text field and press enter and write in a new line and hit in the button the text is showing in one line , It is not recognizing the enter . How do I recognize "enter" in `UITextView` and show the text in new line ??

```
-(IBAction)Acceptmethodtext:(id)sender
{
    textwritingoverit= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 100)];


   textwritingoverit.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
   textwritingoverit.numberOfLines = 0;

    textwritingoverit.text=imagelabeltext.text;
   [imagecross addSubview:textwritingoverit];
}
```

where `textwritingoverit` is `UILabel`,

`imagelabeltext` is `UITextView` and

`imagecross` is `UIView`

Above I have edited my question 
For `textwritingoverit` whenever I have text of single line it took multiple line as the width of the label is fixed  but I need the text to be shown in multiple line when user add new line through `UITExtview`. I need  flexible width of the label depending upon the text.

can anyone help me in this , how could i do so ..

Thanks

Comment: set property "numberOfLines" to zero if u want multi-line label.

Comment: your-label.numberOfLines=5;try to set this property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out: You might missed the `numberOfLines` property for the `UILabel` .

For Ex:

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```